# RecyclerView no se pone horizontal

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, recyclerview

Estoy teniendo problemas para cargar el **`Recyclerview`** de manera **horizontal**; él carga las imagenes bien pero solo vertical aunque yo le cambie la propiedad `orientation` a "vertical".

Les comparto el código de **Inicio** XML, .CS que es donde esta el `Recyclerview` y el XML del `CardView` para ver si es algo que estoy pasando por alto.

Inicio XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/root">
<LinearLayout
                    p1:orientation="horizontal"
                    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
                    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    p1:id="@+id/LayoutAgarra1"
                    p1:background="@drawable/ftb"
                    p1:minWidth="25px"
                    p1:minHeight="25px"
                    p1:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    p1:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        p1:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        p1:scrollbars="horizontal"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Inicio.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Inicio);
                
                mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);
                mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                BusquedaImagenes(); 

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error - " + Ex.Message + DateTime.Now.ToString("G"));
            }

        }
```

CardView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"            
            android:padding="8dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="Peliculas Populares" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Caption"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad lo que  necesitas es únicamente definirlo como Horizontal:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal, false);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

pero en la vista usa "match_parent" y define un alto fijo,por ejemplo 200dp

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    p1:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    p1:scrollbars="horizontal"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Comment: Eso era, muchísimas gracias. Ya estaba al volverme loco. Haha.